# How to detox BASH input or variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am currently using `(tr -d ' ' <<< "$LOC1")`to **detox** *(change spaces into \ / etc.)* the file path. 
This does not work very well though since it only removes spaces instead of correctly formatting like `"File\ path/"`. Since the variable $LOC1 can contail different paths it needs to be "adaptable".


I could not find any solutions that allowed this with a "flexible" file path / variable. So I'm humbly asking here.


*I started learning how to **"script?"** yesterday so excuse me if I couldn't make myself clear.*

```
 #!/bin/bash

LOC1=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select first directory")

LOC2=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select second direcotry")
LOC1=$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$LOC1")
LOC2=$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$LOC2")
clear
rsync -r --info=progress2 --delete-excluded $LOC1 $LOC2
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Your back-up is complete, Press any key to exit..."
```

**Thanks in advance!**

**edit:** The problem was that zenity gives user input to select a directory but doesn't remove the spaces in the path to that directory. it will output for example: `/media/productivity/Seagate backup A/Back-up` instead of `/media/productivity/Seagate\ backup\ A/Back-up`

How do I make it so the script detoxes the file path without knowing how many white spaces there are going to be?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great first question! In addition to Poshi's correct answer, consider adding some sanity checking to the "important" part of your script. You can check the return status of the `rsync` command by assigning `$?` to a variable immediately after `rsync` is run, or you could wrap the command like `if rsync -r ...; then` so that you can handle failures better.

Comment: Not sure what `zenity` returns but you may want to consider adding trailing "/" to keep rsync happy: `rsync ... "$LOC1/" "$LOC2/"`

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is or where you are encountering it. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you don't need to do this path modifications for the script you are running. Just quote all the variables so they can be interpreted properly:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOC1=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select first directory")
LOC2=$(zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select second direcotry")

clear
rsync -r --info=progress2 --delete-excluded "$LOC1" "$LOC2"
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Your back-up is complete, Press any key to exit..."
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! ^^

Comment: @Scriptkiddie27 Variable references like this should almost always be double-quoted -- developing the habit of double-quoting them will save you a lot of headaches if you keep on writing shell scripts. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like leaving them off. Also, I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names, since there are a lot of all-caps names with special meaning to the shell or other utilities, and if you accidentally use one of those... weird things can happen.